# Import all classes (or functions) in all files in folder, as if they were all in the __init__ file

Tags: python, python-import

I have a folder with multiple files containing a lot of different classes. These could all be in one big file but for the sake of making it a bit easier to read I've split it up in multiple files depending on what the classes belongs to.

I'd like to import all classes from all files in the folder into the `__init__` file so that I can import anything from the folder without knowing in what file it belongs to.

Example:

```
/kitchen
 + __init__.py
 + fridge.py
 + stove.py
 + cupboard.py
```

Now I have to do

```
from kitchen.fridge import milk
```

When I'd like to do

```
from kitchen import milk
```

The equivalent of this I can get through in `__init__.py` do:

```
from kitchen.fridge import *
from kitchen.stove import *
from kitchen.cupboard import *
```

And then I can do

```
from kitchen import milk
```

But I'd like it to take all files in the folder without having to specify it explicitly (so that files can be dumped there and then used).

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: "so that files can be dumped there and then used" - Bad idea.

Comment: Is, as abarnert implied, the reason for this that you want to make plugins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very bad idea. If you want to add a mechanism for files to be "dumped there and used", you probably want to come up with a plugin scheme, and explicitly search the plugin directory(ies).

The way you normally do this is to iterate one or more plugin directories with `os.listdir` or `os.walk`, then, for each Python file, use `importlib` (or lower-level equivalents from `imp`, in Python 2.x) to import it by path.

However, if you really insist on faking things this way inside a package, you can do basically the same tricks within the `__init__.py` file, using `os.path.dirname(__file__)` as the plugin directory.

And, if you really insist on doing the equivalent of `from foo import *` instead of `import foo` by path, that's just as easy—or, alternatively, you can use `execfile`.

If you don't know how to do these simple things, or how to look them up in the docs… then you definitely shouldn't be attempting this. So, I won't provide sample code in this case.

Answer (score 8):

```
import os, sys

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
files_in_dir = [f[:-3] for f in os.listdir(dir_path)
                if f.endswith('.py') and f != '__init__.py']
for f in files_in_dir:
    mod = __import__('.'.join([__name__, f]), fromlist=[f])
    to_import = [getattr(mod, x) for x in dir(mod)]
               # if isinstance(getattr(mod, x), type)]  # if you need classes only

    for i in to_import:
        try:
            setattr(sys.modules[__name__], i.__name__, i)
        except AttributeError:
            pass
```

Answer (score -1):

No, there is not. And in addition to that, you shouldn't `import *`, but in the `__init__.py` import explicitly. This way of splitting up modules is common and good practice, by the way.

`import *` is acceptable if you also define an `__all__` attribute in each module, but there is no real benefit of doing so, and it tends to break code analyzers.

Comment: "No, there is not" : well, actually, yes, I did once... and then undid it <g> - as you mention, it's a really bad idea when it comes to maintenance.

Comment: Well, of course there is a way (or many). Anything is possible. But not easy, and not recommended. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Explicit is better than implicit. Don't do this. You can certainly hack something together that does automatic imports to some degree. But it is really not worth it. It is just one extra line per added file in the `__init__.py` and you are done. Simple solutions are better, unless you get a lot out of the more complicated one, which certainly is not the case here.